# VPN Router, VPN Server and deploying VPN at Windows Server

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, windows-server

Related to VPN, mostly we listen and read these terms;

*VPN Router*, *VPN Server* and deploying *VPN at Windows Server*.

Theoretically we know, what VPN is. Moreover, we use some VPN applications.

Please clarify confusions and elaborate.

1. What are functionalities of VPN router and why it is needed?
2. What are functionalities and roles of VPN server?
3. Some of well-known VPNs are Private Internet Access, CyberGhost VPN, BullGuard VPN, NordVPN, Surfshark, etc. Are they use VPN Server and VPN Routers?
4. We can deploy VPN at Windows Server but do VPN providers really use Windows Server as VPN Server?
5. Which type of machine do VPN provider use as VPN server?

With Regards

InTech

Comment: On a general note, VPNs are a fundamental network connectivity method and can be used in many ways for many purposes by many audiences. you seem to be thinking about them from a specific perspective, but asking very broad questions, so the answers are likely to mean less to you than you think. try opening a specific question about what you want to do, and the community can tell you what (if any) application of VPN might be right for you.

Comment: Check out [SoftEther VPN Project](https://www.softether.org/) as it is a VPN Server which you install on a Windows Server. You then configured your routers or firewalls to point port 5555 or another you pick to use perhaps to point to the internal IP address of that server on your private network. A SoftEther VPN client will point to the public IP or DNS name of this server to securely establish the VPN connection. This one is easy to setup, get going and just work on Windows Server. This is a VPN server which is a service on Windows that listens on the needed port(s).

Answer (score 1):

First, understand that VPN is a software service, so a process that clients can connect to to get VPN Service is a "VPN Server". The device a VPN Server is run on could be a Router, a Server, a Desktop, a Laptop, or even a phone or tablet. what makes it a VPN Server is that it runs software that clients can connect to using the appropriate VPN client.

1. Routers define networks, and allow traffic to move from one network to another. VPNs can be used to connect networks together, so if you set up a VPN server on a pair of routers, you can use that VPN to connect networks in two different places. Routers are also the gateway into a network, so you could install a VPN server on the router, and let clients from other networks connect to the router, to then use resources inside the network.
2. VPN Servers allow clients to connect to them, to establish a VPN connection between the two endpoints. The core functionality for a VPN, is the ability to pass encrypted traffic between two endpoints, such that the traffic cannot be observed by operators on networks between those endpoints. using that you might bypass hackers sitting in a coffee shop you stopped at, or connect two corporate networks in different cities, or let employees work from home and still have access to to office network, or as you described,  to hide your internet traffic from your ISP and the web servers you browse. You will have to do your own homework beyond that. the question as asked is out of scope for this site.
3. Those services implement many VPN servers, and allow clients to connect to them. Those are a specific type of VPN however, that is focused on Internet Privacy, so they only offer a small subset of the functionality you could get by architecting solutions using VPN.
4. There are many kinds of VPNs, and yes, some of them can be implemented on windows servers. we can't give you any more details on that without a more specific question, but I would generally recommend that a VPN server should be on a system configured like a gateway, with multi-layered security. once again, hardening servers for pubic access is beyond scope, as the question is asked. if you have a specific question, open a new question on that topic.
5. there is no answer to this. people implement VPNs using many different kinds of hardware. The hardware must be sufficient for the task at the scale you need to operate.

Comment: I am thankful for giving your time. Explanation given by you are really informative.